# Нет изображения python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Подскажите, где можно посмотреть на изображение, которое выдаёт matplotlib?
Запускаю следующий код, но терминал пустой (без ошибок). Сохранять каждый раз - не вариант (но работает)

```
dataFile = open('./data_test_10.csv', 'r')
dataList = dataFile.readlines()
dataFile.close()

all_values = dataList[0].split(',')

image_array = numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]).reshape((28, 28))

plt.imshow(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation=None)

plt.savefig('123.jpg')
```

Comment: С получаемой строкой, открытием файлов и прочего всё в порядке*

Comment: plt.show() https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib-pyplot-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.imshow(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation=None)
plt.show()
```